# Custom location for attached images

Tags: php, functions, directory, docker

I managed to upload images out of where *blog* (WordPress) is installed, and I'm wondering to see how can I update default attached image path.

Few facts:

- The main website is installed on docker. **main.com**
- There is another stand alone WordPress website (*blog*) installed on docker: **main.com/blog**
- There is a subdomain on separate docker where I keep *blog/wp-content*: **media.main.com**
- UPLOAD directory for blog is out of wp-content directory and I can SSH to it by going to where the subdomain docker is: **Docker/doc/media.main.com/blog/files**
- wp-content for blog is renamed to **data**
- 755 for directories and 644 are set for files
- Both dockers are in same IP
- Both websites have their own database, nginx, php hosted on separate dockers

wp-config.php for *blog* website has following:

```
/** upload directory to be outside wp-content */
define( 'UPLOADS', '/media/blog/files' ); // where docker is mounted

/** new name for wp-content */
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/media/blog/data' ); // where docker is mounted
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://media.main.com/blog/data' );
```

I already added the following code to blog functions.php

```
if (defined('UPLOADS')) {
    if (is_dir(UPLOADS)) {
        function files_dir($upload_dir){ 

            $upload_dir['path']    = str_replace( $upload_dir['basedir'], UPLOADS, $upload_dir['path'] );
            $upload_dir['basedir'] = UPLOADS;
            return $upload_dir;
        }
        add_filter('upload_dir', 'files_dir');
        } else {
        error_log('UPLOADS is defined but does not exist: ' . UPLOADS);
    }
}
```

**In summary**: I just not sure how can I have https://media.main.com/blog/files/image.jpg as attached image path in *blog* edit media page rather than: https://main.com/blog//media/blog/files/image.jpg (there is no typo here **//** is what I get)

**ps.0**: https://media.main.com/blog/files/image.jpg is accessible if I manually type it into address bar, but it is not the URL WordPress (*blog*) thinks images are, so I end up to have broken images on WordPress unless I manually update them

[image: **Picture_1**: what I see in edit media page as attached image path]

[image: **Picture_2**: What I see in edit media page as attached image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing your line in wp-config.php to

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'media/blog/files' ); // where docker is mounted
```

Ie, get rid of the first /.

Let me know if this works.

EDIT

If you can't change the definition of UPLOADS you could strip out the forward slash out with code. Try changing your code to this...

```
$upload_dir['path'] = str_replace( $upload_dir['basedir'], ltrim( UPLOADS, '/'), upload_dir['path'] );
```

Comment: Definitely we can't do that, as it has been mentioned, it is "mounted" to a docker volume/disk/partition

Comment: After I applied your new suggestion, found two things: First, I got  **https://main.com/blog//media/blog/files/u/image.jpg** and second the image.jpg is no longer accessible by **https://media.main.com/blog/files/image.jpg**

Can't we just hard code the path we believe image.jpg needs be hosted? We always know when we upload a picture, it should be accessible by https://media.main.com/blog/files/image.jpg, so just return https://media.main.com/blog/files/[whatever image name is]